# "Invalid project" error form Google API Javascript client

Tags: javascript, google-api

I am starting to play with Google Cloud DNS and I would like to hack a small Javascript project for listing/editing zones / resourceRecords.
I started on the "[Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/cloud-dns/getting-started)" page which explains and offers some samples of the JS query/edit process. The thing is I got at some point where Google API responds with and "Invalid project" error for all supplied values of the 'project' parameter. I am using the clientID for the web application from the Google Developer Console for the oAuth part.  The project name I am using is the string named PROJECT ID in google (the same one I am using successfully in the gcloud command-line tools or the on-line JS testground).

According to this: https://content.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/dns/v1beta1/rpc the **dns.resourceRecordsSets.list** requires two parameters: *managedZone* and *project*. If I do a call without params I get this:

```
[
 {
  "error": {
   "code": 400,
   "message": "Required value: managedZone",
   "data": [
    {
     "domain": "global",
     "reason": "required",
     "message": "Required value: managedZone"
    },
    {
     "domain": "global",
     "reason": "required",
     "message": "Required value: project"
    }
   ]
  },
  "id": "gapiRpc"
 }
]
```

which is perfectly fine... 
Next I add the project and the managedZone params and then I get this:

```
[
 {
  "error": {
   "code": 400,
   "message": "Invalid parameter: project",
   "data": [
    {
     "domain": "global",
     "reason": "invalidParameter",
     "message": "Invalid parameter: project",
     "locationType": "parameter",
     "location": "project"
    }
   ]
  },
  "id": "gapiRpc"
 }
]
```

Here is my API call code.... I also tried checking the JS code from Google with no success in finding the "Invalid parameter" code...

```
gapi.client.load('dns', 'v1beta1', function() {

          var request = gapi.client.dns.resourceRecordSets.list({
            'project': 'lolName',
            'managedZone': 'lolZone'
          });

          request.execute(function(resp) {

            console.log(resp);

            if (resp.code == 200) {                      
                 // do some displaying
            }
            else {
              document.getElementById('content').appendChild(document.createTextNode('Error: ' + resp.message));
            }
          });
```